# Vue2 JSX can't extract common templates into a seperate js file

Tags: vuejs2, jsx

I want to extract common templates in jsx into another file, but I got errors that said h function wasn't defined, what should I do???

in a .vue file:

```js
          <el-radio disabled label={item.label} border={conf.border} key={item.value}   class="option-draggable" >
            <svg-icon name='sort-operator' class='item-option-drag sort-operator-position' />
            <div class='flex-container'>
              <ContentEditableArea
                vModel={item.label}
                contenteditable={item.value !== this.$variablesModules.optionComponentVariables.SPECIALOPTIONS.other.value}
                class={this.optionActiveVal === item.value ? 'option-content-editable-active contenteditable' : 'contenteditable'}
                vOn:contenteditable-toggle={status => updateActiveOptionValue.call(this, status, item.value)}
                ref={`option-${item.value}`}
              />
              {this.isActive ? (<svg-button class="svg-buttom-option-delete" name='option-delete' vOn:click_native={() => conf.__slot__.options.splice(index, 1) } />) : '' }
            </div>
          </el-radio>
```

I want to exract common template(as content bellow) into seperate js file:

```
            <svg-icon name='sort-operator' class='item-option-drag sort-operator-position' />
            <div class='flex-container'>
              <ContentEditableArea
                vModel={item.label}
                contenteditable={item.value !== this.$variablesModules.optionComponentVariables.SPECIALOPTIONS.other.value}
                class={this.optionActiveVal === item.value ? 'option-content-editable-active contenteditable' : 'contenteditable'}
                vOn:contenteditable-toggle={status => updateActiveOptionValue.call(this, status, item.value)}
                ref={`option-${item.value}`}
              />
              {this.isActive ? (<svg-button class="svg-buttom-option-delete" name='option-delete' vOn:click_native={() =
```

What should I do, my homies!

As

content above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a component to reuse your code:

```js
<template>
    <svg-icon name='sort-operator' class='item-option-drag sort-operator-position' />
            <div class='flex-container'>
              <ContentEditableArea
                vModel={item.label}
                contenteditable={item.value !== this.$variablesModules.optionComponentVariables.SPECIALOPTIONS.other.value}
                class={this.optionActiveVal === item.value ? 'option-content-editable-active contenteditable' : 'contenteditable'}
                vOn:contenteditable-toggle={status => updateActiveOptionValue.call(this, status, item.value)}
                ref={`option-${item.value}`}
              />
              {this.isActive ? (<svg-button class="svg-buttom-option-delete" name='option-delete' vOn:click_native={() => conf.__slot__.options.splice(index, 1) } />) : '' }
            </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item: {required: true},
    optionActiveVal: {required: true},
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```